# What shopify solutions I should use in order to have fully customized user interface to draw on the product?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I want to create a shopify shop where there’s freehand drawing interface that users can use to draw something on the product. I want to design and develop the User Interface myself - I must have a full control the interface.

This is going to be a print on demand product.

I’ve tried checking the Storefront API and Admin API. As I’m not too familiar  with shopify, the documentation failed to answer my questions. I never wasn’t sure I was reading the corresponding topic

Comment: One of the possible ways this could be done is by writing a react(or any js) app. To make it work, think of how you would embed a js app within a php project.